# Dynamically adding distinct sets of Integers

Tags: java, set

I am writing a program where a user adds a set of numbers with a name and a set of values, in this format:

Example:

add set1:{1,3,5,7}

I am to extract the name (set1), and pass that to a new Set. Then add the numbers to the set.

Normally, it would be easy to just make a new Set and add the numbers. For example:

```
Set<Integer> newSet = new Set<Integer>();
newSet.add(1);
newSet.add(3);
newSet.add(5);
newSet.add(7);
```

My confusion is with the fact that every time a user adds a new set with a new name, it would need a unique variable name, but I can't change that dynamically in my code.

For instance if a user issues the command

```
add set1:{1,3,5,7}
```

ideally I could do this:

```
Set<Integer> set1 (variable name taken from user input) = new Set<Integer>();
```

But I know this is not possible. So given that I can't have unique variable names for each set, how do I distinguish between created sets when I want to add numbers to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a HashMap would work?

```
HashMap<String, Set<Integer>> sets = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>();
```

You would load up all of the integers into the set. Then you'd load them into the map with

```
sets.put(*somestring*, *aset*);
```

Then retrieve with

```
sets.get(*somestring*);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map of sets using name of a set as a key:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```